# Does the set of commuting endomorphisms always admit a cyclic endomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let be $C(u)$ the set of commuting endomorphisms with $u$ over a complex-valued vector space of finite dimension $n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$.

I call $v$ a cyclic endomorphism iff all its eigenspaces are one dimensional vector space.

I'd like to know if $C(u)$ contains at least always a cyclic endomorphism.

My proof strategy is to distinguish multiple cases:

(1) if $u$ is diagonalizable: I can build such an *invertible* cyclic endomorphism by considering the eigenspaces

(2) if $u$ is nilpotent: that's precisely my issue, I'm trying to mess with Jordan reduction, but failed to do so.

(3) general case: I write $u = d + n$, such that $d$ is diagonalizable and $n$ nilpotent and $dn = nd$, I get an invertible cyclic endomorphism $v$ which commutes with $d$, but that's not enough to get $vu = uv$.

Comment: What do you mean by plane? two-dimensional subspace or hyperplane or ...? Because if you take your vector space to be $\mathbb C$, there are no planes contained in it and the answer to your question would be no.

Comment: @James I meant one-dim vector space but I might be wrong in my terminology I will edit.

Comment: In (3), if it commutes with $d$, why does it have to commute with $u$?

Comment: @James I think it's edited.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier That's actually false… Right, I thought that $v$ invertible and $dn  = nd$ and $vd = dv$ would suffice to get $nv = vn$ and then $vu = uv$, but that's false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conjecture is true.

Let $A\in M_n(K)$ where $K$ is an algebraically closed field.

Then the Jordan form of $A$ is as follows

$A=Pdiag(\lambda_1 I_{k_1}+J_{k_1},\cdots,\lambda_p I_{k_p}+J_{k_p})P^{-1}$ where $J_r$ is the nilpotent Jordan block of dimension $r$, $k_1+\cdots+k_p=n$ and the $\lambda_i \in K$ are eigenvalues of $A$ that are NOT NECESSARILY DISTINCT.

Let $\mu_1,\cdots,\mu_p$ be $p$ DISTINCT elements of $K$.

Let $B=Pdiag(\mu_1 I_{k_1}+J_{k_1},\cdots,\mu_p I_{k_p}+J_{k_p})P^{-1}$; then $B\in C(A)$ and is cyclic.

REMARK. On a general field $K$, a cyclic matrix is s.t. its characteristic and minimal polynomials are the same. I don't know (I did not think about) if the previous result holds in this general case.